# How to use Processing to plot serial data

Tags: arduino, processing

I'm trying to plot some sensor data that's being read in through the serial port. I found this Processing example code of a 2D plotter, and I'm trying to alter it to work for my application.

The programming is a bit over my head though. I can see that it's getting data for the three lines from the three equation classes. I'd like to replace the part where is reads the mouseX with a variable or something that points to the newest sensor update. The sensor data is continuously updated in the void `Draw()` loop.

```
/**
 * RollingGraph
 * This sketch makes ise of the RollingLine2DTrace object to
 * draw a dynamically updated plot.
 */

import org.gwoptics.graphics.graph2D.Graph2D;
import org.gwoptics.graphics.graph2D.traces.ILine2DEquation;
import org.gwoptics.graphics.graph2D.traces.RollingLine2DTrace;

class eq implements ILine2DEquation{
    public double computePoint(double x,int pos) {
        return mouseX;
    }
}

class eq2 implements ILine2DEquation{
    public double computePoint(double x,int pos) {
        return mouseY;
    }
}

class eq3 implements ILine2DEquation{
public double computePoint(double x,int pos) {
    if(mousePressed)
        return 400;
    else
        return 0;
    }
}

RollingLine2DTrace r,r2,r3;
Graph2D g;

void setup(){
    size(600,300);

    r  = new RollingLine2DTrace(new eq() ,100,0.1f);
    r.setTraceColour(0, 255, 0);

    r2 = new RollingLine2DTrace(new eq2(),100,0.1f);
    r2.setTraceColour(255, 0, 0);

    r3 = new RollingLine2DTrace(new eq3(),100,0.1f);
    r3.setTraceColour(0, 0, 255);

    g = new Graph2D(this, 400, 200, false);
    g.setYAxisMax(600);
    g.addTrace(r);
    g.addTrace(r2);
    g.addTrace(r3);
    g.position.y = 50;
    g.position.x = 100;
    g.setYAxisTickSpacing(100);
    g.setXAxisMax(5f);
}

void draw(){
    background(200);
    g.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure if that code you have is what you need, but here is a simple program that takes in serial input and makes a line graph. Hope this helps.

```
    import processing.serial.*;
    Serial myPort;
    int x = 0;


    void setup() {
      size(600, 400);
      println(Serial.list());  //list of available serial ports
      String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //replace 0 with whatever port you want to use.
      myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
    }


    void draw() {
    }


    void serialEvent(Serial myPort) {
      int inByte = myPort.read();
      println(inByte);
      stroke(90, 76, 99);
      //vertical line with height varying according to input
      line(x, height, x, height - inByte); 
      if (x >=width) {
        x=0;
        background(0);
      }
      x++;
    }
```